# Java String[] помощь

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Нужна помощь допустим есть массив:

```
String[] s = {"26", "8", "15", "12", "11", "12"};
```

Нужно сделать так что бы если ищем "12" в результате в одну переменную заносилось:

```
String a = "1212";
```

а если строки "12" нет в массиве то

```
String a = "0";
```

Написал следующий код но он работает не правильно:

```
  String[] s = {"26", "8", "15", "12", "11", "12"};
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i].equals("12")) {
            d += s[i];
            System.out.println(d);
        } else {
            d = "0";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: Что значит неправильно?.. Программа не компилируется, падает или выходные данные не соответствуют ожиданиям?.. У вас, кстати, в первом цикле надо бы `i++` вместо `++i`

Comment: Спасибо. Выходные данные не соответствуют.

Comment: Вы дойдя до 11 обнуляете вашу строку. В итоге значение её равно "012"

Comment: Это я понимаю не понимаю как пофиксить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант можно проверить строку на пустоту

```
String d = "";
String[] s = {"26", "8", "15", "12", "11", "12"};
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
       if (s[i].equals("12")) {
           d += s[i];
       }
   }
if(d.isEmpty())
   d = "0";
System.out.println(d);
```